# Error while using Panadas-TA with backtesting API

Tags: python, pandas, back-testing, pandas-ta

I keep getting this error when using any indicator in Panadas-Ta with the backtestingapi
here is the code for the indicator and the backtesting api

```
Indicators must return (optionally a tuple of) numpy.arrays of same length as `data` (data shape: (1280,); indicator "squeeze(H,L,C)"shape: , returned value: None
```

Backtesting:

```
import pandas as pd
from backtesting.lib import SignalStrategy
from backtesting import Backtest
from backtesting.test import GOOG
import pandas_ta as ta
from strat_sqz import*

df = pd.read_csv('15minAAPLyear1month1.csv',index_col='time', parse_dates=True)

class Teststrategy(SignalStrategy):
    def init(self):
        super().init()
        self.sqz = self.I(squeeze, self.data.High ,self.data.Low, self.data.Close)
        signal = self.sqz == 0
        self.set_signal(entry_size=10)
   
bt = Backtest(df, Teststrategy, cash=10_000, commission=.002)
stats = bt.run()
print(stats)
```

Indicator from Panada-ta

```
from numpy import nan as npNaN
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas_ta.momentum import mom
from pandas_ta.overlap import ema, linreg, sma
from pandas_ta.trend import decreasing, increasing
from pandas_ta.volatility import bbands, kc
from pandas_ta.utils import get_offset
from pandas_ta.utils import unsigned_differences, verify_series
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def squeeze(high, low, close, bb_length=None, bb_std=None, kc_length=None, kc_scalar=None, mom_length=None, mom_smooth=None, use_tr=None, mamode=None, offset=None, **kwargs):
    """Indicator: Squeeze Momentum (SQZ)"""
    # Validate arguments
    bb_length = int(bb_length) if bb_length and bb_length > 0 else 20
    bb_std = float(bb_std) if bb_std and bb_std > 0 else 2.0
    kc_length = int(kc_length) if kc_length and kc_length > 0 else 20
    kc_scalar = float(kc_scalar) if kc_scalar and kc_scalar > 0 else 1.5
    mom_length = int(mom_length) if mom_length and mom_length > 0 else 12
    mom_smooth = int(mom_smooth) if mom_smooth and mom_smooth > 0 else 6
    _length = max(bb_length, kc_length, mom_length, mom_smooth)
    high = verify_series(high, _length)
    low = verify_series(low, _length)
    close = verify_series(close, _length)
    offset = get_offset(offset)

    if high is None or low is None or close is None: return

    use_tr = kwargs.setdefault("tr", True)
    asint = kwargs.pop("asint", True)
    detailed = kwargs.pop("detailed", False)
    lazybear = kwargs.pop("lazybear", False)
    mamode = mamode if isinstance(mamode, str) else "sma"

    def simplify_columns(df, n=3):
        df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()
        return [c.split("_")[0][n - 1:n] for c in df.columns]

    # Calculate Result
    bbd = bbands(close, length=bb_length, std=bb_std, mamode=mamode)
    kch = kc(high, low, close, length=kc_length, scalar=kc_scalar, mamode=mamode, tr=use_tr)

    # Simplify KC and BBAND column names for dynamic access
    bbd.columns = simplify_columns(bbd)
    kch.columns = simplify_columns(kch)

    if lazybear:
        highest_high = high.rolling(kc_length).max()
        lowest_low = low.rolling(kc_length).min()
        avg_ = 0.25 * (highest_high + lowest_low) + 0.5 * kch.b

        squeeze = linreg(close - avg_, length=kc_length)

    else:
        momo = mom(close, length=mom_length)
        if mamode.lower() == "ema":
            squeeze = ema(momo, length=mom_smooth)
        else: # "sma"
            squeeze = sma(momo, length=mom_smooth)

    # Classify Squeezes
    squeeze_on = (bbd.l > kch.l) & (bbd.u < kch.u)
    squeeze_off = (bbd.l < kch.l) & (bbd.u > kch.u)
    no_squeeze = ~squeeze_on & ~squeeze_off

    # Offset
    if offset != 0:
        squeeze = squeeze.shift(offset)
        squeeze_on = squeeze_on.shift(offset)
        squeeze_off = squeeze_off.shift(offset)
        no_squeeze = no_squeeze.shift(offset)

    # Handle fills
    if "fillna" in kwargs:
        squeeze.fillna(kwargs["fillna"], inplace=True)
        squeeze_on.fillna(kwargs["fillna"], inplace=True)
        squeeze_off.fillna(kwargs["fillna"], inplace=True)
        no_squeeze.fillna(kwargs["fillna"], inplace=True)
    if "fill_method" in kwargs:
        squeeze.fillna(method=kwargs["fill_method"], inplace=True)
        squeeze_on.fillna(method=kwargs["fill_method"], inplace=True)
        squeeze_off.fillna(method=kwargs["fill_method"], inplace=True)
        no_squeeze.fillna(method=kwargs["fill_method"], inplace=True)

    # Name and Categorize it
    _props = "" if use_tr else "hlr"
    _props += f"_{bb_length}_{bb_std}_{kc_length}_{kc_scalar}"
    _props += "_LB" if lazybear else ""
    squeeze.name = f"SQZ{_props}"

    data = {
        squeeze.name: squeeze,
        f"SQZ_ON": squeeze_on.astype(int) if asint else squeeze_on,
        f"SQZ_OFF": squeeze_off.astype(int) if asint else squeeze_off,
        f"SQZ_NO": no_squeeze.astype(int) if asint else no_squeeze,
    }
    df = DataFrame(data)
    df.name = squeeze.name
    SQZ_ON = squeeze_on.astype(int) if asint else squeeze_on,
    return (df['SQZ_ON'])
```

Output of the indicator by itself:

```
2022-01-31 20:00:00    0
2022-01-31 19:45:00    0
2022-01-31 19:30:00    0
2022-01-31 19:15:00    0
2022-01-31 19:00:00    0
                      ..
2022-01-03 05:15:00    0
2022-01-03 05:00:00    0
2022-01-03 04:45:00    1
2022-01-03 04:30:00    1
2022-01-03 04:15:00    1
```

Sample of data used:

```
                       Open    High     Low   Close  Volume
time                                                       
2022-01-31 20:00:00  174.38  174.50  174.30  174.40   35912
2022-01-31 19:45:00  174.40  174.40  174.20  174.30   23927
2022-01-31 19:30:00  174.30  174.44  174.30  174.40    7009
2022-01-31 19:15:00  174.48  174.48  174.31  174.31    8708
2022-01-31 19:00:00  174.28  174.49  174.28  174.48    7538
                    ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
2022-01-03 05:15:00  178.08  178.16  177.99  178.09   14732
2022-01-03 05:00:00  177.88  178.10  177.81  178.08   14637
2022-01-03 04:45:00  177.87  177.89  177.76  177.89   15416
2022-01-03 04:30:00  178.08  178.12  177.81  177.82   15625
2022-01-03 04:15:00  178.26  178.34  177.76  178.08   15259
```

The same error happens with any indicator from the panda-ta library. I'm not quite sure what the error message means. I have tried transforming the return of the indicator to an a numpy array but that didn't work either Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the issue got resolved by converting the data to `Panda Series` when calling the Indicator function:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_ta as ta

self.rsi = self.I(ta.rsi, pd.Series(self.data.Close), 14)
```

I am directly using the `rsi` indicator from pandas-ta https://github.com/twopirllc/pandas-ta/blob/main/pandas_ta/momentum/rsi.py

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

tnx. pd.Series(self.data.Close) work for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).